# Can I add return air vents to improve air conditioning in some rooms?

Tags: air-conditioning

The return air system in my 46 yo home utilizes the stud space not a duct system.  My bedroom has a vent and maintains a temp  about 5 to 10 degrees lower than the other bedrooms.

My question:  Can I cut return air vents in these other bed rooms to lower the temperatures and make them more comfortable?

Comment: I take it the other bedrooms have no vents whatsoever?

Answer (score 2):

If you keep the doors to the other (warmer) bedrooms closed, try opening them. If this helps, then a return air duct, bypass vent around the door, or a door grille could help.

If opening the doors doesn't help the other rooms, you can try adjusting the vents (open more in the hot rooms, less in the cold rooms) to balance the air flow.

Also check the windows & blinds. If the warm rooms get more sun exposure, close their blinds or rotate them so hot air rises toward the glass. This can make several degrees difference during the day.